# Filter message body in elastic search using Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-query

I have JSON in Kibana UI containing below information along with other details :--

```
host.name       abcd

 message        2020-07-29 03:59:19,393 -0700 INFO  [http-nio-8080-exec-2139] abchohfowhofnfnnfnwlnflw 
                CLIENT_ID=MNOPQR xysbxs
```

I want to filter only the part CLIENT_ID=MNOPQR as search result in Kibana . Basically I want to get all the client_id name on the host  abcd .

Is it possible to get the data ?

Comment: is MNOPQR xysbxs is  complete id or just MNOPQR

Comment: MNOPQR is complete id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to filter for host.name='abcd'

Then using the pipe line processors you can extract the client id like below

```
POST _ingest/pipeline/_simulate  
{  
  "pipeline": {  
  "description" : "parse multiple patterns",  
  "processors": [   
    {   
      "grok": {     
        "field": "message",  
        "patterns": [ "CLIENT_ID=%{NOTSPACE:client_value}" ]   
           }   
    }   
  ]    
  },   
"docs":[   
  {   
    "_source": {   
      "message": "2020-07-29 03:59:19,393 -0700 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-2139] abchohfowhofnfnnfnwlnflw CLIENT_ID=MNOPQR xysbxs"    
    }     
  }      
  ]   
}       



And the result is 

{
  "docs" : [
    {
      "doc" : {
        "_index" : "_index",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "_id",
        "_source" : {
          "message" : "2020-07-29 03:59:19,393 -0700 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-2139] abchohfowhofnfnnfnwlnflw CLIENT_ID=MNOPQR xysbxs",
          "client_value" : "MNOPQR"
        },
        "_ingest" : {
          "timestamp" : "2020-07-29T18:25:29.07763Z"
        }     
      }
    }
  ]
}

enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

Kibana’s query language is based on Lucene query syntax. You should be able to filter the host.name field with the exact hostname you're after and wildcard the message similarly to below:

```
host.name: "abcd" AND message: *CLIENT_ID=MNOPQR*
```

Comment: I basically want to find all client_id  value which is running on the host abcd